# CASE WHEN statement with GROUP BY on Broadest Dimension

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a CASE WHEN with the results GROUPING and categorizing the broadest dimension in a SQL table. Right now the table looks like this:

| Month | adgroup | keyword_name | ad_type | Click_percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | trucks | pickups | banner | .3 |
| 1 | sedan | four-door | video | .2 |
| 1 | SUVs | tough | link | .7 |
| 2 | trucks | offroad | banner | .6 |
| 2 | sedan | two-door | video | .7 |
| 2 | SUVs | spacious | link | .8 |

The broadest dimension here is Month and I have a benchmark identifier that determines a unique month being "Over" if the click_percent for Banner AND Video going over .5. Link clicks do not have a say in the results of this categorization. My SQL statement right now looks something like this

```
SELECT *,
    CASE
      WHEN ad_type in ('banner', 'video') and click_% > .5 THEN "Great"
      ELSE "Low"
    END AS benchmark
FROM table
```

As a result right now, I am getting:

| Month | adgroup | keyword_name | ad_type | Click_percent | benchmark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | trucks | pickups | banner | .3 | Under |
| 1 | sedan | four-door | video | .2 | Under |
| 1 | SUVs | tough | link | .7 | Under |
| 2 | trucks | offroad | banner | .6 | Over |
| 2 | sedan | two-door | video | .7 | Over |
| 2 | SUVs | spacious | link | .8 | Under |

Unfortunately with Link also being a value under ad_type, it is getting its own categorization under the same month. I think my biggest problem is that I am not grouping the results of my CASE WHEN by Month. Each month should have one distinct value, either "Over" or "Under", regardless of how many ad_types or other more diverse dimensions. Some other notes are that this query is part of a bigger query to create this view and click_percent is an aggregated field.

This is what my results should look like:

| Month | adgroup | keyword_name | ad_type | Click_percent | benchmark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | trucks | pickups | banner | .3 | Under |
| 1 | sedan | four-door | video | .2 | Under |
| 1 | SUVs | tough | link | .7 | Under |
| 2 | trucks | offroad | banner | .6 | Over |
| 2 | sedan | two-door | video | .7 | Over |
| 2 | SUVs | spacious | link | .8 | Over |

Here is another failed query I tried for the sake of troubleshooting:

```
SELECT month, benchmark
from(
    SELECT
    month, ad_type, click_percent,
    CASE WHEN ad_type in ('banner', 'video') and click_% > .5 THEN "Over"
      ELSE "Under"
    END AS benchmark
    FROM table
    group by month, ad_type, click_percent)
  group by month, benchmark
```

Any advice or documentation would be very helpful! Let me know what you think!

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.  Also, edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: Start over. You cannot possibly be getting a value of "Under" as you claim from your first query

Answer (score 0):

If you want months with an "over" flag, you can use aggregation:

```
SELECT month,
       (CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN ad_type = 'banner' THEN click_% END) > 0.5 AND
                  MAX(CASE WHEN ad_type = 'video' THEN click_% END) > 0.5 
             THEN 'over' ELSE 'low'
        END) as benchmark
FROM table
GROUP BY month;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
select *, 
    if(countif(ad_type in ('banner', 'video') and click_percent > .5) over(partition by month) = 2, 'Over', 'Under') as benchmark
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SELECT month,
(CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN ad_type = 'banner' THEN click_% END) > 0.5 AND
MAX(CASE WHEN ad_type = 'video' THEN click_% END) > 0.5 THEN 'over' ,
ELSE 'low'
END) as benchmark
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Month